# Create Records in PhpMyAdmin with Checkbox

Tags: php, html

How do I add a new record to my `Financial` table in my database by just selecting a `Checkbox` on the user edit page?

For example, I want to add a value in the `Input` field and by checking the `Checkbox` this value will be shown in the `Financial` table in my database.

In the `Financial` table there are some other attributes that should be set to 'NULL' such as `'id, user_id, value, date, decription, created_at, updated_at'`

```
    <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Profit Division(week)</label>
                          <input type="text" name="money9" value="{{ $users->money9 }}" class="form-control">
                       <input type='checkbox' name="extract[]" class="form-control" value="Profits Division" />
</div>
    <?php
    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['extract'])){
      $extract = $_POST['extract'];

      foreach($extract as $value){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO financial(decription) VALUES ('".$value."')";
      mysql_query($sql);
      }
    }       
    ?>
```

Comment: Hey, its quiet difficult to understand what you are trying to do. You want to insert a record to your database table. But only if the checkbox is checked? And you just want to insert the description?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, that's right, I would just like to show the input text and the value text

Comment: Thanks. Do you use multiple form-groups?

Comment: oh yes there are more checkboxes to be placed but I would like to start with just one

Comment: Okay thanks, I just need to sort some things out. One more question, if the checkbox is checked you will insert something into the table. What about the `money9` input? Is that important, does this have to belong to the checkbox? You are just inserting $value which is just "Profits Division"?

Comment: oh yes, this is a user edit page, I would like to record the value entered in Input text money9 in the "Financial" table but only with the checkbox checked.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand your problem and I think I could fix it.

So, you have a form with many elements. One element contains a text field which is `"name="money9"` above. If the checkbox of that field is checked, you want to insert the value inside the textfield, correct?

```html
 <form action="test.php" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profit Division(week)</label>
    <input type="text" name="extract[100]" value="{{ $users->money9 }}" class="form-control">
    <input type='checkbox' name="checked[]" class="form-control" value="100" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profit Division(week)</label>
    <input type="text" name="extract[101]" value="{{ $users->money9 }}" class="form-control">
    <input type='checkbox' name="checked[]" class="form-control" value="101" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Here I created you a form, with two elements. You can create as many element as you wish later on.

The text values are stored in extract array. They are iterated with a number, which has to match with the value of the checkbox.

Now If we send that data to PHP, we will just fetch the array of the checked checkboxes, get the value and search the matching value of that text field.

```
<?php

  foreach($_GET["checked"] as $value)
  {
    //This is the value of the text field where the checkbox is checked
    $data = $_GET["extract"][$value];

    //insert $data into database
  }

?>
```

$data contains the value of the text field, and ONLY the text fields, where the checkbox is checked. This value can be inserted into the database.

Here is a example, which I tried on my server:

First, I just select the second checkbox with the value "Second One". If I send that form...PHP will echo the correct value only, which is `"Second One"`

[image: First image]

Comment: thanks for the help but i need to take the value entered in the input text money9 and register in the table "Financial".
Example: money9 is in table "users", now I need to register the value entered in table "Financial"

Comment: It would be something like INSERT INTO `My_DB2`.`financial` (
id,
`user_id`,
decription)
VALUES (
NULL, '2', '2', '2038', '2020-01-10', 'Profit Division', ''
);